# elasticsearch vserver install error

Tags: elasticsearch, server, linux-kernel, virtuozzo

I want to install elasticsearch on a vserver:

- virtuozzo container
- Ubunutu 16.04

When typing `apt-get install elasticsearch`, I've getting the following error message:

```
Selecting previously unselected package elasticsearch.
(Reading database ... 40410 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../elasticsearch_5.5.0_all.deb ...
Creating elasticsearch group... OK
Creating elasticsearch user... OK
Unpacking elasticsearch (5.5.0) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Setting up elasticsearch (5.5.0) ...
Job for systemd-sysctl.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 elasticsearch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've also tried installing with `export SKIP_SET_KERNEL_PARAMETERS=true && apt-get install elasticsearch`, but I got the same error message.

This is output of `systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service`:

```
● systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-07-13 19:08:34 CEST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysctl.service(8)
           man:sysctl.d(5)
 Main PID: 21550 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 13 19:08:34 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21550]: Couldn't write '1' to 'fs/protected_hardlinks', ignoring: No such file or directory
Jul 13 19:08:34 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21550]: Couldn't write '1' to 'kernel/kptr_restrict', ignoring: Permission denied
Jul 13 19:08:34 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21550]: Couldn't write '262144' to 'vm/max_map_count', ignoring: Permission denied
Jul 13 19:08:34 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21550]: Couldn't write '176' to 'kernel/sysrq', ignoring: Permission denied
Jul 13 19:08:34 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21550]: Couldn't write '1' to 'fs/protected_symlinks', ignoring: No such file or directory
Jul 13 19:08:34 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21550]: Couldn't write '1' to 'kernel/yama/ptrace_scope', ignoring: No such file or directory
```

This is the (relevant!?) output of `journalctl -xe`:

```
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net groupadd[21716]: group added to /etc/group: name=elasticsearch, GID=117
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net groupadd[21716]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=elasticsearch
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net groupadd[21716]: new group: name=elasticsearch, GID=117
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net useradd[21722]: new user: name=elasticsearch, UID=111, GID=117, home=/home/elasticsearch, shell=/bin/false
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net usermod[21727]: change user 'elasticsearch' password
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net chage[21732]: changed password expiry for elasticsearch
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21758]: Couldn't write '176' to 'kernel/sysrq', ignoring: Permission denied
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21758]: Couldn't write '1' to 'fs/protected_symlinks', ignoring: No such file or directory
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21758]: Couldn't write '262144' to 'vm/max_map_count', ignoring: Permission denied
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21758]: Couldn't write '1' to 'kernel/yama/ptrace_scope', ignoring: No such file or directory
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21758]: Couldn't write '1' to 'fs/protected_hardlinks', ignoring: No such file or directory
Jul 13 19:16:18 h2707501.stratoserver.net systemd-sysctl[21758]: Couldn't write '1' to 'kernel/kptr_restrict', ignoring: Permission denied
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You are facing this issue due to miss configured `dpkg` 
Package responsible for all kind of installations.

> sudo apt-get remove --purge getdeb-repository

It will clear all the repository data and you will be good to go.